Avoiding underflow errors in calculation of $e^{-z}j_n(iz)$
I would like some advice on how to handle underflow errors in the calculation of functions of the form $e^{-z}j_n(iz)$.
As an example, consider the following code:
E^-1000 SphericalBesselJ[0, 1000 I]
N[%]
N[%%, 10]


During evaluation of In[53]:= General::munfl: Exp[-1000.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
Out[54]= 0. + 0. I
Out[55]= 0.0005000000000 + 0.*10^-14 I

The final quantity to be calculated is of a reasonable size, but it is formed from the product of a huge number (the Bessel function) and a tiny one. Evaluating at fixed precision produces a good number, but straightforward application of N (or putting the function into e.g. Plot) produces the munfl error.
(For context, I am handling functions based on this, like ComplexFocusElectricE and its normalization via \[Alpha]QC, from my ComplexFocus package. The spherical Bessel functions will come in a range of (integer) orders, and they will be evaluated at arguments with large imaginary part and small but nonzero real part. The normalization factor $\sim e^{-z}$ is fixed for the entire calculation.)
Is there a good way to deal with this? I'm open to all avenues, from N hacks, to other built-in functions that deal with the asymtptotics better, to mathematical transformations.

Not sure if this will work for complex inputs, but maybe a transformation where the tiny E^-x term is handled in logarithmic space like N[Exp[Log[SphericalBesselJ[0,1000I]]-1000]]?

To very high precision this is just 1/2000, i.e., N[E^-1000 SphericalBesselJ[0, 1000 I] // FunctionExpand // TrigToExp // Simplify, 100] // Rationalize[#, 0] &

Mathematica says that SphericalBesselJ[0, x I] == Sinh[x]/x.  Using this result may enable your expressions to be rearranged into a form that avoids over/underflows.  E.g. for large x, Sinh[x] is very close to E^x/2.

Go higher precision.  N[%,40] gives you a non zero number.

I've done N@N[expr, $MachinePrecision] in such cases when I want machine precision, but it can't be calculated using machine precision.
